# SQL Server :: FULL backup not recorded in msdb.dbo.backupset and log file unusually large

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, sql-server-2019, dbcc

I have a server that is running SQL Server 2019 but the databases are still on `Compatibility level 110` (so that means SQL Server 2012 basically).

We take a FULL backup every night and I indeed see the files backed up in the right folder every day. But then if I run [this query](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/05/13/how-to-find-last-full-backup-time-and-size-for-database-interview-question-of-the-week-173/) , and I add `backup_finish_date desc` to check when the last FULL backup was taken I see that the date is months back:

[image]

So I found [this guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/951288/sql-server-records-a-backup-operation-in-the-backupset-history-table-w) that says it might be a bug in SQL Server and ask to run this check:

```
USE msdb
GO
SELECT server_name, database_name, backup_start_date, is_snapshot, database_backup_lsn
FROM backupset
```

*"...In the result, notice the database_backup_lsn column and the is_snapshot column. An entry that represents an actual database backup operation has the following characteristics:
The value of the database_backup_lsn column is not 0.
The value of the is_snapshot column is 0."*

[image]

All good to me, it looks like `database_backup_lsn column is not 0` and `is_snapshot column is 0`

Then the guide says to run this query to verify the integrity of the backup:

```
WITH backupInfo AS( SELECT database_name AS [DatabaseName], 
name AS [BackupName], is_damaged AS [BackupStatus],
backup_start_date AS [backupDate],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY database_name 
ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC) AS BackupIDForDB 
FROM msdb..backupset) SELECT DatabaseName 
FROM backupinfo WHERE BackupIDForDB = 1 and BackupStatus=1
```

[image]

The result is nothing!

And the guide says: *"...If the this query returns any results, it means that you do not have good database backups after the reported date."*

So now I'm scared that our backup is fucked up. We take the backup with `CHECKSUM` but we haven't run `DBCC CHECKDB` in ages so we are maybe (successfully and with `CHECKSUM`) taking backups of corrupted databases. Let's run:

```
DBCC CHECKDB('msdb') WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

[image]

And the result is nothing, so it seems all good.

**And at the same time the size of the log file (155GB) appears unusually large compared to the data file size of 514GB**

**EDIT:**

I take Full backup every night and Log backup every hour

**EDIT 2:**

Brent Ozar suggests to run `SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;` and as result I have `NOTHING` nearly everywhere:

[image]

Comment: In regards to the log, how frequently do you perform transaction log backups? You mention you do a full backup daily, but nothing on the transaction log backups.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, I take FULL backup daily and Log Backup every hour

Comment: Having log_reuse_wait_desc of NOTHING is fine.




For LOG_BACKUP see: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-is-log_reuse_wait_desc-saying-log_backup-after-doing-a-log-backup/






Paul Randal used to work at Microsoft on the database engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...And the solution was:

We use `Always On availability groups` and the backups were taken on the failover environment (the replica server).

I see on the web a lot of question similar to mine an they don't really have an answer. I believe I'm not the only one that faced this problem